# Expand `ifthenelse` immediately

Tags: macros, ifthenelse

Consider this script:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\thesissize}{SHORT}
\begin{document}
   \setcounter{page}{
    %3
    \ifthenelse{
    \equal{\thesissize}{SHORT}
    }{3}{2}
  }
  hey
\end{document}
```

Compiling this script gives the error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
```

I suspect that this is due to `\ifthenelse` not being evaluated at the time of executing `\setcounter`. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can't use `\ifthenelse` inside `\setcounter`. Change the order:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\thesissize}{SHORT}
\begin{document}
   \ifthenelse{\equal{\thesissize}{SHORT}}
    {\setcounter{page}{3}}{\setcounter{page}{2}}


  hey
\end{document}
```

Expandable tests are possible with `expl3` and `etoolbox`. For both you should store the reference text in a command:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{expl3,etoolbox}
\newcommand{\thesissize}{SHORT}
\newcommand{\shortsize}{SHORT}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\setcounter{page}{\tl_if_eq:NNTF\thesissize\shortsize{3}{2}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setcounter{page}{\ifdefequal{\thesissize}{\shortsize}{3}{2}}

  hey
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the reason?

Comment: ifthenelse is not expandable.

Comment: I added two more versions.

Answer (score 2):

Another version of a string comparison using the pdfTeX macro `\pdfstrcmp`. The following uses the `pdftexcmds` package to make it available to all engines under the same name:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ifstreq[2]
  {%
    \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{#2}=0
  }
\makeatother

\newcommand\thesissize{SHORT}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{\ifstreq{\thesissize}{SHORT}3\else2\fi}
hey
\end{document}
```

If a LaTeX syntax is preferred one can use

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ifstreq[2]
  {%
    \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{#2}=0
      \expandafter\@secondofthree
    \fi
    \@secondoftwo
  }
\providecommand\@secondofthree[3]{#2}
\makeatother

\newcommand\thesissize{SHORT}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{\ifstreq{\thesissize}{SHORT}{3}{2}}
hey
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

No packages.

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcommand{\thesissize}{SHORT}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\tmp{SHORT}
\ifx\tmp\thesissize\relax\setcounter{page}{3}\else\setcounter{page}{2}\fi

\thepage

\renewcommand\tmp{NOT SHORT}
\ifx\tmp\thesissize\relax\setcounter{page}{3}\else\setcounter{page}{2}\fi

\thepage
\end{document}
```

[image]

The expandable version:

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcommand{\thesissize}{SHORT}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\tmp{SHORT}
\setcounter{page}{\ifx\tmp\thesissize3\else2\fi}

\thepage

\renewcommand\tmp{NOT SHORT}
\setcounter{page}{\ifx\tmp\thesissize3\else2\fi}

\thepage
\end{document}
```